# cannot access private member in the same class

Tags: c++, class, struct, private

I tried to declare a public member function with a private struct, but it didn't work. Can someone help me with this? Here's the header file

```
class LinkedList
{
public:
   LinkedList();
   ~LinkedList();
   ...
   //I tried to add LinkedList also not working
   //void deleteNode(const LinkedList::Node* n);
   void deleteNode(const Node* n);

private:
    struct Node
    {
        std::string value;
        Node *next;
    };
```

Comment: Move the `private: ...` etc section above the public section within the same class. After you do this, think hard about how someone is supposed to supply the public `deleteNode` function a pointer to a type they know nothing about (because it's private). In short, barring some unseen friending this model doesn't make a whole lotta sense.

Comment: Thank you guys, I didn't think though about this 

Comment: @WhozCraig Having a public `void deleteNode(const Node* n);` makes the `LinkedList::Node` - from the perspective of being able to access and use `LinkedList::Node` - public again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
class LinkedList
{
public:
   LinkedList();
   ~LinkedList();

   void deleteNode(const Node* n);

private:
    struct Node
    {
        std::string value;
        Node *next;
    };
};
```

`Node` is declared after `void deleteNode(const Node* n);`, so the compiler won't know what `Node` is.

You should do this instead:

```cpp
class LinkedList
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        std::string value;
        Node *next;
    };

public:
   LinkedList();
   ~LinkedList();

   void deleteNode(const Node* n);

};
```